# Faye how to calculate max numbers of clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

i'm using faye with ruby server for publish-subscribe messaging and it works well, but I have some doubts:

1. how can i estimate the max numbers of clients that can receive messages simultaneously? It should be related at my message size but I don't now how to measure this value. I think this is pretty important to know because I want to prevent any kind of delay in the future.
2. how can i simulate N clients connected simultaneously? Can be done via capybara or there is a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might try load testing. Here are a couple options to get you started:

https://github.com/dbrady/tourbus
https://flood.io/